# antd DatePicker view is not rendering correcty

Tags: reactjs, antd

```
import { Button, Layout, DatePicker } from 'antd'
<div><DatePicker /></div>
```

[image]

antd calendar gives me this weird collapse view

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: @Justcode plain usage or under getFieldDecorator, just added above

Comment: When is this happening? Resizing the window?

Comment: all sizes if page not uses grid system , above case antd xs size to sm @BoyWithSilverWings

Comment: @MustafaKahraman In my case, it doesn't produce any weird behaviour https://jd8hl.csb.app/  Here is the code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/so-53975570-jd8hl could you change this code and reproduce the actual behaviour?